# How can I click buttons on a web page? Java/C#

Tags: c#, java, button, click, onclick

I've a very specific question:
How can I click in certain buttons on a web page?
Without that thing of coordinates. =D
What I really want, is a script that search for a Button (or more) with specific name and clicks it.

Imagine:
You open your browser and go to google page, than you run the script and, for example, it clicks the Search button.

If possible, I want a answer wich uses java or C#.

Thanks in advance for reading this,
and sorry for my bad english.

Edit:

Ok. Assuming that I'll use WatiN, can you rapidly explain how do I "put" this on my c# prog?
I want WatiN to be running on a button_click event. Like: When you enter the URL on my prog and press "OK" the prog will click that especific button that I've told you before.
Sorry if I've messed it up, I'me a truly noob with great ideas =s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I WatiN all the time for screen scraping web sites: http://watin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

For .NET, [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) will do what you want.  In fact, the very first example on the home page, shows you how to search google.